# Find a time value in a range in between two times

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need help in getting the formula to find a value in range C3:H6 that is equal or greater than the time now(=TEXT(now(),"hh:mm:ss am/pm")) and less than or equal to time now + 59mins.

Here are some examples:
Time now is 7:30 am it would return 8:00 am
Time now is 5:00 pm it would return 5:00 pm
Time now is 3:01 am it would return 4:00 am
Time now is 11:59 pm it would return 12:00 am

Here a sample of the range of time that I have I and want the formula on the in I3
[image]

Comment: please share a link to the sheet in the screenshot or [make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this formula: `=LET(slots, FLATTEN(F2:H4), time_now, NOW()-int(NOW()), FILTER(slots, slots>=time_now, slots<(time_now+1/24)))` where `F2:H4` is the range with the time slots.

Please note that if the time now is 5:00:01 PM, the output will be 6:00 PM.

Comment: This works, Now how do I put conditional formatting on the C3:H6 range that would highlight the time if it's the same as what is reflected on the return column? I tried the "is equal to" rule and it's not working. Maybe it's because of the difference in format?

This is the format of the time in range C3:H6 8:00:00 AM.

Comment: Format should not be the cause: all dates and times in Google Sheets are numbers and compared as such.  Could you create a test sheet with what you tried and share it here, please?